# Prestashop add another field to the the address form

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have been trying to add another two non-mandatory fields to the address pages, (user page, admin page, etc)

I created two columns in the `ps_address` and named *address3* and *address4* and changed available files in version 1.6.0.11 according to [this article](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/268687-how-do-i-add-new-fields-in-the-registration-form-ps-1541/#entry1626917)

I was able to add the new adreess3 and address4 fields in the country address settings. But there is no text field to add address3 and address4 in the `AddressesController` and the customer add addresses list.

Following is my **modified** AddressesController file.

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2015 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2015 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/

class AdminAddressesControllerCore extends AdminController
{
    /** @var array countries list */
    protected $countries_array = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->required_database = true;
        $this->required_fields = array('company', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode', 'other', 'phone', 'phone_mobile', 'vat_number', 'dni');
        $this->table = 'address';
        $this->className = 'Address';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->addressType = 'customer';
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();

        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'delete' => array(
                'text' => $this->l('Delete selected'),
                'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?'),
                'icon' => 'icon-trash'
            )
        );

        $this->allow_export = true;

        if (!Tools::getValue('realedit'))
            $this->deleted = true;

        $countries = Country::getCountries($this->context->language->id);
        foreach ($countries as $country)
            $this->countries_array[$country['id_country']] = $country['name'];

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_address' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center', 'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'),
            'firstname' => array('title' => $this->l('First Name'), 'filter_key' => 'a!firstname'),
            'lastname' => array('title' => $this->l('Last Name'), 'filter_key' => 'a!lastname'),
            'address1' => array('title' => $this->l('Address')),
            'postcode' => array('title' => $this->l('Zip/Postal Code'), 'align' => 'right'),
            'city' => array('title' => $this->l('City')),
            'country' => array('title' => $this->l('Country'), 'type' => 'select', 'list' => $this->countries_array, 'filter_key' => 'cl!id_country'));

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_select = 'cl.`name` as country';
        $this->_join = '
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'country_lang` cl ON (cl.`id_country` = a.`id_country` AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.')
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c ON a.id_customer = c.id_customer
        ';
        $this->_where = 'AND a.id_customer != 0 '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_CUSTOMER, 'c');
    }

    public function initToolbar()
    {
        parent::initToolbar();
        if (!$this->display)
            $this->toolbar_btn['import'] = array(
                'href' => $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminImport', true).'&import_type=addresses',
                'desc' => $this->l('Import')
            );
    }

    public function initPageHeaderToolbar()
    {
        if (empty($this->display))
            $this->page_header_toolbar_btn['new_address'] = array(
                'href' => self::$currentIndex.'&addaddress&token='.$this->token,
                'desc' => $this->l('Add new address', null, null, false),
                'icon' => 'process-icon-new'
            );

        parent::initPageHeaderToolbar();
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Addresses'),
                'icon' => 'icon-envelope-alt'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text_customer',
                    'label' => $this->l('Customer'),
                    'name' => 'id_customer',
                    'required' => false,
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Identification Number'),
                    'name' => 'dni',
                    'required' => false,
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => $this->l('DNI / NIF / NIE')
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Address alias'),
                    'name' => 'alias',
                    'required' => true,
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' &lt;&gt;;=#{}'
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'label' => $this->l('Other'),
                    'name' => 'other',
                    'required' => false,
                    'cols' => 15,
                    'rows' => 3,
                    'hint' => $this->l('Forbidden characters:').' &lt;&gt;;=#{}'
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            )
        );
        $id_customer = (int)Tools::getValue('id_customer');
        if (!$id_customer && Validate::isLoadedObject($this->object))
            $id_customer = $this->object->id_customer;
        if ($id_customer)
        {
            $customer = new Customer((int)$id_customer);
            $token_customer = Tools::getAdminToken('AdminCustomers'.(int)(Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminCustomers')).(int)$this->context->employee->id);
        }

        $this->tpl_form_vars = array(
            'customer' => isset($customer) ? $customer : null,
            'tokenCustomer' => isset ($token_customer) ? $token_customer : null
        );

        // Order address fields depending on country format
        $addresses_fields = $this->processAddressFormat();
        // we use  delivery address
        $addresses_fields = $addresses_fields['dlv_all_fields'];

        // get required field
        $required_fields = AddressFormat::getFieldsRequired();

        // Merge with field required
        $addresses_fields = array_unique(array_merge($addresses_fields, $required_fields));

        $temp_fields = array();

        foreach ($addresses_fields as $addr_field_item)
        {
            if ($addr_field_item == 'company')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Company'),
                    'name' => 'company',
                    'required' => in_array('company', $required_fields),
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' &lt;&gt;;=#{}'
                );
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('VAT number'),
                    'col' => '2',
                    'name' => 'vat_number',
                    'required' => in_array('vat_number', $required_fields)
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'lastname')
            {
                if (isset($customer) &&
                    !Tools::isSubmit('submit'.strtoupper($this->table)) &&
                    Validate::isLoadedObject($customer) &&
                    !Validate::isLoadedObject($this->object))
                    $default_value = $customer->lastname;
                else
                    $default_value = '';

                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Last Name'),
                    'name' => 'lastname',
                    'required' => true,
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&amp;lt;&amp;gt;,;?=+()@#"�{}_$%:',
                    'default_value' => $default_value,
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'firstname')
            {
                if (isset($customer) &&
                    !Tools::isSubmit('submit'.strtoupper($this->table)) &&
                    Validate::isLoadedObject($customer) &&
                    !Validate::isLoadedObject($this->object))
                    $default_value = $customer->firstname;
                else
                    $default_value = '';

                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('First Name'),
                    'name' => 'firstname',
                    'required' => true,
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&amp;lt;&amp;gt;,;?=+()@#"�{}_$%:',
                    'default_value' => $default_value,
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'address1')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Address'),
                    'name' => 'address1',
                    'col' => '6',
                    'required' => true,
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'address2')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Address').' (2)',
                    'name' => 'address2',
                    'col' => '6',
                    'required' => in_array('address2', $required_fields),
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'address3')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Address').' (3)',
                    'name' => 'address3',
                    'col' => '6',
                    'required' => in_array('address3', $required_fields),
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'address4')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Address').' (4)',
                    'name' => 'address4',
                    'col' => '6',
                    'required' => in_array('address4', $required_fields),
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'postcode')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Zip/Postal Code'),
                    'name' => 'postcode',
                    'col' => '2',
                    'required' => true,
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'city')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('City'),
                    'name' => 'city',
                    'col' => '4',
                    'required' => true,
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'country' || $addr_field_item == 'Country:name')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Country'),
                    'name' => 'id_country',
                    'required' => in_array('Country:name', $required_fields) || in_array('country', $required_fields),
                    'col' => '4',
                    'default_value' => (int)$this->context->country->id,
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => Country::getCountries($this->context->language->id),
                        'id' => 'id_country',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    )
                );
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'label' => $this->l('State'),
                    'name' => 'id_state',
                    'required' => false,
                    'col' => '4',
                    'options' => array(
                        'query' => array(),
                        'id' => 'id_state',
                        'name' => 'name'
                    )
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'phone')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Home phone'),
                    'name' => 'phone',
                    'required' => in_array('phone', $required_fields) || Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST'),
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST') ? sprintf($this->l('You must register at least one phone number.')) : ''
                );
            }
            elseif ($addr_field_item == 'phone_mobile')
            {
                $temp_fields[] = array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Mobile phone'),
                    'name' => 'phone_mobile',
                    'required' =>  in_array('phone_mobile', $required_fields) || Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST'),
                    'col' => '4',
                    'hint' => Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST') ? sprintf($this->l('You must register at least one phone number.')) : ''
                );
            }
        }

        // merge address format with the rest of the form
        array_splice($this->fields_form['input'], 3, 0, $temp_fields);

        return parent::renderForm();
    }

    public function processSave()
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('submitFormAjax'))
            $this->redirect_after = false;

        // Transform e-mail in id_customer for parent processing
        if (Validate::isEmail(Tools::getValue('email')))
        {
            $customer = new Customer();
            $customer->getByEmail(Tools::getValue('email'), null, false);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($customer))
                $_POST['id_customer'] = $customer->id;
            else
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This email address is not registered.');
        }
        elseif ($id_customer = Tools::getValue('id_customer'))
        {
            $customer = new Customer((int)$id_customer);
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($customer))
                $_POST['id_customer'] = $customer->id;
            else
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This customer ID is not recognized.');
        }
        else
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This email address is not valid. Please use an address like bob@example.com.');
        if (Country::isNeedDniByCountryId(Tools::getValue('id_country')) && !Tools::getValue('dni'))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The identification number is incorrect or has already been used.');

        /* If the selected country does not contain states */
        $id_state = (int)Tools::getValue('id_state');
        $id_country = (int)Tools::getValue('id_country');
        $country = new Country((int)$id_country);
        if ($country && !(int)$country->contains_states && $id_state)
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You have selected a state for a country that does not contain states.');

        /* If the selected country contains states, then a state have to be selected */
        if ((int)$country->contains_states && !$id_state)
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An address located in a country containing states must have a state selected.');

        $postcode = Tools::getValue('postcode');
        /* Check zip code format */
        if ($country->zip_code_format && !$country->checkZipCode($postcode))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Your Zip/postal code is incorrect.').'<br />'.Tools::displayError('It must be entered as follows:').' '.str_replace('C', $country->iso_code, str_replace('N', '0', str_replace('L', 'A', $country->zip_code_format)));
        elseif(empty($postcode) && $country->need_zip_code)
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('A Zip/postal code is required.');
        elseif ($postcode && !Validate::isPostCode($postcode))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The Zip/postal code is invalid.');

        if (Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST') && !Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile'))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must register at least one phone number.');

        /* If this address come from order's edition and is the same as the other one (invoice or delivery one)
        ** we delete its id_address to force the creation of a new one */
        if ((int)Tools::getValue('id_order'))
        {
            $this->_redirect = false;
            if (isset($_POST['address_type']))
                $_POST['id_address'] = '';
        }

        // Check the requires fields which are settings in the BO
        $address = new Address();
        $this->errors = array_merge($this->errors, $address->validateFieldsRequiredDatabase());

        if (empty($this->errors))
            return parent::processSave();
        else
            // if we have errors, we stay on the form instead of going back to the list
            $this->display = 'edit';

        /* Reassignation of the order's new (invoice or delivery) address */
        $address_type = ((int)Tools::getValue('address_type') == 2 ? 'invoice' : ((int)Tools::getValue('address_type') == 1 ? 'delivery' : ''));
        if ($this->action == 'save' && ($id_order = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order')) && !count($this->errors) && !empty($address_type))
        {
            if (!Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders SET `id_address_'.$address_type.'` = '.Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID().' WHERE `id_order` = '.$id_order))
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while linking this address to its order.');
            else
                Tools::redirectAdmin(Tools::getValue('back').'&conf=4');
        }
    }

    public function processAdd()
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('submitFormAjax'))
            $this->redirect_after = false;

        return parent::processAdd();
    }

    /**
     * Get Address formats used by the country where the address id retrieved from POST/GET is.
     *
     * @return array address formats
     */
    protected function processAddressFormat()
    {
        $tmp_addr = new Address((int)Tools::getValue('id_address'));

        $selected_country = ($tmp_addr && $tmp_addr->id_country) ? $tmp_addr->id_country : (int)Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT');

        $inv_adr_fields = AddressFormat::getOrderedAddressFields($selected_country, false, true);
        $dlv_adr_fields = AddressFormat::getOrderedAddressFields($selected_country, false, true);

        $inv_all_fields = array();
        $dlv_all_fields = array();

        $out = array();

        foreach (array('inv','dlv') as $adr_type)
        {
            foreach (${$adr_type.'_adr_fields'} as $fields_line)
                foreach (explode(' ', $fields_line) as $field_item)
                    ${$adr_type.'_all_fields'}[] = trim($field_item);

            $out[$adr_type.'_adr_fields'] = ${$adr_type.'_adr_fields'};
            $out[$adr_type.'_all_fields'] = ${$adr_type.'_all_fields'};
        }

        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Method called when an ajax request is made
     * @see AdminController::postProcess()
     */
    public function ajaxProcess()
    {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('email'))
        {
            $email = pSQL(Tools::getValue('email'));
            $customer = Customer::searchByName($email);
            if (!empty($customer))
            {
                $customer = $customer['0'];
                echo Tools::jsonEncode(array('infos' => pSQL($customer['firstname']).'_'.pSQL($customer['lastname']).'_'.pSQL($customer['company'])));
            }
        }
        die;
    }

    /**
     * Object Delete
     */
    public function processDelete()
    {
        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($object = $this->loadObject()))
            if (!$object->isUsed())
                $this->deleted = false;

        return parent::processDelete();
    }

    /**
     * Delete multiple items
     *
     * @return boolean true if succcess
     */
    protected function processBulkDelete()
    {
        if (is_array($this->boxes) && !empty($this->boxes))
        {
            $deleted = false;
            foreach ($this->boxes as $id)
            {
                $to_delete = new Address((int)$id);
                if ($to_delete->isUsed())
                {
                    $deleted = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $this->deleted = $deleted;
        }

        return parent::processBulkDelete();
    }
}
```

I also tried clearing cache using the Advanced Parameters > Performance and also did a manual cache clearance as well.

What might the problem be as to not showing the new address fields in backend or the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Try also delete (no worries it will be rebuid) class_index.php file at cache folder of Your store